# Flutter command still not working even though flutter/bin is in my $PATH

Tags: flutter, dart, path, zsh

I'm trying to install flutter and I've followed all the steps from each website I've read but zsh is still saying "command not found: flutter".  [Terminal output after echo $PATH and trying a flutter command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgidm.png). Below is the exact line in my .zshrc file:

export PATH="$PATH:Users/gabrielworthington/Documents/Developer/flutter/bin"

Any suggestions on what to do? Thanks.

Comment: Are you on linux or are you somehow using zsh on windows?? your flutter path looks like it is a windows path, but the rest of your path variable looks like a linux path.

Comment: `Users/gabrielworthington/Documents/Developer/flutter/bin` is a relative path, not an absolute path.

Comment: I see, then should you not make it an absolute path?

Comment: @h8moss My comment wasn't meant to be a reply to you.  And yes, paths in `PATH` almost always should be absolute.

Comment: @jamesdlin My bad, got confused and thought you were the author of the question.

Comment: @h8moss I'm on Mac

Comment: @jamesdlin how do I make it absolute?

Comment: `/Users/gabrielworthington/Documents/Developer/flutter/bin` would be an absolute path.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths

Answer (score 0):

Do you run

```
source $HOME/.<rc file>.
```

to refresh your path?

[Flutter doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path)

PS: I can´t comment so I had to post an answer